# Using ppx and nndist to find nearest neighbour of each type

Tags: r, spatial, nearest-neighbor, spatstat

For a dataset with three covariates and a treatment indicator I'm trying to find each individual's nearest neighbour. In particular, I want to find the nearest neighbour in each of the treatment groups.

```
# Generate a treatment indicator factor
treatment <- factor(data_train[,"a"], levels = c("0", "1"), labels = c("Untreated", "Treated"))

# Put the covariate data into 'points' format
pointpattern <- ppx(data = data.frame(data_train[, c("Z1", "Z2", "Z3")], "Treatment" = treatment), coord.type = c("s", "s", "s", "m"))

# Find the nearest neighbour of each type
dists <- nndist(X = pointpattern, by = marks(pointpattern))
```

However the object 'dists' is only a vector, which appears to be the nearest neighbour with the treatment group completely ignored.

I've spent nearly a full day trying to figure out what Im doing wrong - please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument `by` is not recognised by the function `nndist.ppx` which you are using in this example.

This is about "classes and methods" in `R`. The function `nndist` is generic; when you call `nndist` on an object of class `"ppx"`, the system invokes the function `nndist.ppx` which is the "method" for this class.

You can check the capabilities of `nndist.ppx` by looking at its help file; it does not support the argument `by`.

There are other `nndist` methods which do recognise the argument `by`, for example `nndist.ppp`, and I guess you were looking at the documentation for that.

We will update the code in `spatstat` so that this capability is available for `nndist.ppx` as well.

In the meantime, you can use the function `nncross.ppx` to find nearest distances from one group of points to another. Here's how to get the result you wanted:

```
Y <- split(pointpattern) # divide into groups
m <- length(Y) # number of groups
n <- npoints(pointpattern)
result <- matrix(, n, m) # final results will go here
partresults <- list() # collect results for each group here
for(i in 1:m) {
  Yi <- Y[[i]]
  ni <- npoints(Yi)
  a <- matrix(, ni, m)
  a[,i] <- nndist(Yi)
  for(j in (1:m)[-i]) 
     a[,j] <- nncross(Yi, Y[[j]], what="d")
  partresults[[i]] <- a
}
split(result, marks(pointpattern)) <- partresults
```

Then `result` is the matrix of distances you wanted.

Comment: Update: `nndist(X, by)` now works for `ppx` objects, in the development version of `spatstat` (version 1.63-3.037 and later)